# Getting public post with Instagram API

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, instagram-api

I am building an app using the SwiftInstagram API that will allow users to download the video from an Instagram post from the post link.

I have user authentication working, but when I try accessing media from a post with a valid media id like so:

```swift
       import SwiftInstagram

       let api = Instagram.shared

       // ...

        api.media(withShortcode: "B0obb3dAMh3", success: { (media) in
            print("got it")
        }) { (error) in
            print(error)
        }
```

I get an error saying that the endpoint has been retired.

I know that the Instagram API is undergoing changes and has been limiting what we can do with it, but is it really not even possible to access a public post anymore?

The reason I ask is that I know there are plenty of apps on the Apple app store like 'Insaver' that allow you to download and save videos from public Instagram posts (without even having to authenticate your account) that still work perfectly ...

The note on the API deprecation on top of the Instagram developer site (https://www.instagram.com/developer/) also includes a link to the Instagram Graph API, but, from my understanding, using that only grants you access to Business and Creator account media.

Anyway, all I am trying to do is access videos from PUBLIC Instagram posts -- does anyone know how to do this in Swift / iOS?

^ I am assuming this is achievable given the fact that existing apps like Insaver still work and can access public posts.

Comment: No idea about your question but keep in mind that Instagram posts are copyrighted and can not be used without poster's permission, even if they're publicly posted.

Comment: @MuhammedGül I get that, but if that is the case then I'm confused how apps like Insaver that allow you to save any public post from Instagram exist?

Comment: They violate copyright rules. If the owner of the saved Instagram post sues the app's developer the app probably will be removed from App Store and developer will need to pay compensation. But since no one really checks such apps they exist illegally.